# Is there a particular reason why some binary operators in F# like (+) , (>) , (<) only accept parameters that must be the same type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, f#

Languages like `C#` allow us to write code as below :

```
// C#
Console.WriteLine($"{3 > 2.3}"); // compare an int with a double
```

But `F#` doesn't allow us to do that. For example,

```
// F#
printfn "%A" (3 > 4)            // fine
printfn "%A" (3.0 > 4.0)        // fine
printfn "%A" (3 > 4.0)          // wrong
```

Is there a particular reason why some binary operators in `F#` like `(+)` , `(>)` , `(<)`  only accept parameters that must be the same type?

Comment: In C# these operators _also_ accept parameters of the same type. But in C# there is magic (i.e. automatic) type conversion. When you write `3 > 2.3`, the compiler inserts a conversion `((double)3) > 2.3`, but you don't see it. This is a source or many errors.

Comment: I always like to point to [this twitter comment](https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1081254571110916096) by a C# language designer. Implicit conversions are a huge problem from a backwards-compatibility point of view, and make it hard to a) understand how an API is actually used and b) evolve an api in new directions.

Comment: you can define your operators in F# to be what you want.  But in general in functional programming you want to be quite explicit about types as they detect problems with correctness of a program at compile time ( as opposed to just correctness of syntax ).  It's often why you can be pleasnatly surprised with F# programs working first time once you get them to compile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# does not do implicit type conversion. Implicit conversions can create problems, and it's part of why so many people have mixed emotions around javascript. For example please enjoy this classic javascript poem. Implicit conversion is fundamental to what makes this poem possible.

```
> Array(16).join('wat' - 1) + ' Batman'
'NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN Batman'
```

What is 3 > "4", how about "4" > 3?  You may have answers for these that make sense to you however there's a lot of valid ways to interpret what the implicit conversion should be. The ambiguity here may be less obvious with 3 > 4.0, however when you have a driving philosophy of explicit conversion it's better to apply it universally.